# Image classification in python with matching score

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am having a code for image classification. It gives me result that image belongs to which class. But i want to print matching score or percentage matching of the image with all classes. so that i can fix some threshold value. Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, BatchNormalization, Activation
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.constraints import maxnorm
from keras.utils import np_utils

classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64,64,3 ),activation="relu"))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
classifier.add(Flatten())

classifier.add(Dense(128 , kernel_initializer ='uniform' , activation = 'relu')) 
classifier.add(Dense(10 , kernel_initializer ='uniform' , activation = 'softmax'))

classifier.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy' , metrics = ['accuracy']) 


from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        '/code/train',
        shuffle=True,
        target_size=(64,64),
        batch_size=5,
        class_mode='categorical',
        classes=["shiv", "kart", "nall","sur","harshi","nag","saura","rajan","man","abhim"])

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        '/code/validation',
        shuffle=True,
        target_size=(64,64),
        batch_size=5,
        class_mode='categorical',
        classes=["shiv", "kart", "nall","sur","harshi","nag","saura","rajan","man","abhim"])

from IPython.display import display
from PIL import Image

classifier.fit_generator(
        training_set,
        steps_per_epoch=80,
        epochs=12,
        validation_data=test_set,
        validation_steps=100)
        
 from keras_preprocessing import image
 files_dir = '/code/test_image_clasification1'
 files = os.listdir(files_dir)
    for f in files:
        image_path = files_dir + '/' + f
        test_image = image.load_img(image_path,target_size = (64, 64))
        test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
        test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
        result = classifier.predict(test_image)
        #classes = classifier.predict_classes(test_image)
        #print (classes)
        labels=["shi","kart","nal","sure","harshi","nage","saura","rajan","man","abhim"]
        indx=np.argmax(result)
    print(f,labels[indx])
```

Here lables[indx] gives me image belongs to which class. But i require some function so that i can get match score of test image with all classes.

Comment: That information is literally in your result array, particularly at result[indx]

Comment: Just print(f, labels)

Answer (score 0):

It's in result?

```
print(list(zip(labels, result)))
```

Comment: @ Frederik Bode , Thanks for reply. But its only printing the file name and all class names. I want the matching percentage of image with other classes. Something like this :                                                                                                                                             Pic1.jpg shiv 95% , kart 32%, .....